# CUPS Server Error "client-error-not-possible"

Tags: networking, printing, canon, chromebook, crouton

I'm attempting to add a network printer for the first time on my Crouton enabled Chromebook.  I'm running XFCE4 on top of Ubuntu 14.04.5.  I downloaded the necessary PPD source files for the Canon Pixma MG5720 (connected only to Wifi) that I own, and I get through all of the steps of adding a new printer right until the "Describe Printer" prompt.  Clicking forward at that point brings the CUPS Server "client-error-not-possible" message.  I have the smbclient installed...giving Terminal the command:

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

returns:

```
smbclient is already the newest version.
```

I'm a little stuck, and out of my depth as a long-time windows user.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in Ubuntu 18.04 with a Xerox printer and your suggestion of updating the smbclient like below actually helped.
`sudo apt-get install smbclient`

I just wanted to note that for some it can be a solution. For you obviously not. But, I could not comment yet (50 reputation needed) so opted for making an 'answer' here.